# Can an existing object be passed into a Boost.Serialization load?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm using Boost's Serialization library to save and load the state of an app. The objects rely on a TCP connection. Right now I'm distributing a pointer to the TCP connection into the objects after they're deserialized, but tracking down all of the objects that are created in the loading process is proving to be unwieldy.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass the TCP connection into the objects as they're being created, perhaps as a constructor argument. I can find instructions on using non-default constructors with the serialization library, but these assume that the arguments themselves can be constructed using only information stored in the Archive file. Is it possible to somehow inject a pre-existing object in the deserialization process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went with creating a new archive class using `boost::archive::text_iarchive` as a base class, like so:

```
struct my_iarchive : public boost::archive::text_iarchive {
    my_iarchive(std::istream& is, socket* sock) :
        boost::archive::text_iarchive(is), sock(sock) {}

    socket* sock;
};
```

Then, in the deserialization method we can get into our user data by casting the archive to `my_iarchive`.

```
template <class Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    m_socket = (static_cast<my_iarchive&>(ar)).sock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load non default-constructible objects and pass them any parameters you wish by means of defining `load_construct_data` for that class. Please see [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors) for details.